# allow different types for one parameter like a sum type of String and StringRes int

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any proper way to declare a parameter as union type that accepts multiple types, so e.g. you could call a function as `showMessage(message = "foobar")` or `showMessage(message = R.string.foobar)`

Something like

```
  fun showMessage(message: String? OR Int? = null,
                  title: String? OR Int? = null
                  ){
     when (message) 
       is String -> ...
       is Int -> ...
     ...
  }
```

Perhaps with Any? But it should give a compile time error for non-string objects. Perhaps with multiple functions? But that would need 2^n functions for n parameters, should have less

Comment: Nothing like this exists, You need to declare multiple methods for that. Perhaps You can make wrapper object/interface for your parameters?

Comment: If you want to show an Int you can still convert it and pass it as String.

Comment: Can you show more of `showMessage` so we can see maybe how you could abstract something into an interface that could be used to generically get what you want?

Comment: @JaysonMinard: It is like a wrapper around android's AlertDialog.Builder that uses named parameters rather than the builder pattern. The builder has overloaded methods for strings and ressource ids

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you cannot do this currently. In most cases, I'd just create proper overloads for your functions. An alternative would be to abstract the type by a custom class.

```
class Text(val value: String) {
    constructor(intValue: Int) : this(intValue.toString())
}

fun showMessage(message: Text, title: Text) {
    val msgText = message.value
    val titleText = title.value
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    showMessage(Text(1), Text("2"))
    showMessage(Text("1"), Text(2))
}
```

If you like, you can use the experimental [`inline` classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-classes.html) that were introduced with Kotlin 1.3. Just make `Text` an `inline class` then. It will remove the heap allocation overhead.